# Is it correct to say 'math specialized school' or maybe 'math magnet school about a school with many math lessons?

Tags: vocabulary

There are such schools here in post-Soviet Union countries where they teach math intensively, say, at least 1 lesson per day. Here we call them **specialized schools**.
They can have a different profile, say foreign languages or sports.

What do you call this phenomenon? How can I explain that I'd like to send my son to a '**specialized math**' school rather than a '**default**' neighborhood school? Will '**specialized math**' school sound OK? If not, what's a better name for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1 lesson per day for a given subject is "intensive?"

Comment: What school level are we talking about here? Elementary/primary, high school/secondary, college/university?

Comment: At least one per day, and often more. I meant secondary/high school

Comment: I would say 'a school that specialises in maths'. (You use the American _math_ in your heading, but the British _maths_ in the body of the question!)

Comment: @KateBunting You got great eyes!

Comment: @TypeIA the Eastern Bloc education system is quite a bit different - unless you opt for a vocational school you follow a rather general curriculum all the way through your entire primary and secondary education, and the "specializations" amount to eg. 1 hour a week of History more at the expense of 1 hour of Maths.

Comment: Education terminology is highly specific to different countries (and possibly even parts of countries, as with Scotland and Northern Ireland) - terminology in the UK is very different to the US, and Canada, Australia, India, etc, have their own version. I can see "[specialist maths schools](https://russellgroup.ac.uk/policy/case-studies/specialist-maths-schools/)" used in the UK, but it wouldn't be heard in the US. You need to decide which version of English you want.

Comment: math-intensive school

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, we currently refer to secondary schools that specialise in a particular subject as an *[academy](https://www.gov.uk/types-of-school/academies)*, although this has other implications as well.

For example, a *Performing Arts Academy* is a school that teaches all subjects, but has facilities and a particular focus on performing arts. Other schools in my personal area that have been academised include the specialised subjects of "leadership" and "sports". Around the country there are various others. Other institutions that teach just *one* subject, either as an extra-curricular activity for school-age children or as a form of non-advanced education for adults may also be called an "academy".

There are schools of mathematics, or "mathematic schools" in the UK, but these appear to be *higher* education (eg tertiary education, post-grad etc). As mathematics is a *compulsory* subject in all UK secondary schools, I would not expect a state school at that level to specialise in it, although I cannot be authoratitive on that.

This may be different in other English-speaking countries.

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution to problems of "too many adjectives and pre-modifiers" is to use a relative clause.

English usually puts adjectives before the noun, so "specialized school" is good. But "specialized maths school" or is awkward: its not clear if specialized is modifying "maths" or "school".

Relative clauses can be much "heavier", you can put a preposition to indicate the relationship that "maths" has. If you have adjective that is formed as a participle, consider using it as the verb in a relative clause:

Using "default" is okay, but "the local school" probably means the same, or it may be more natural to use the particular school name. (If I recall, Russian schools tend to be numbered rather than named)

> I want to send my daughter to a school that specialises in maths, rather than School 10.

(A small historical aside) Now there is an compound phrase "Mathematics specialist school", in England (not even the UK) from an old government initiative to create specialised schools, but this refers to a particular scheme (that doesn't even exist anymore). At one point, about 15 years ago, nearly all schools picked a "specialism" because the government was offering extra money. Some might still use the term in advertising (even though the scheme has ended)